# An Issue In List View Adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I Have A ListView In Dialog & I Want Set An Item TextColor In ListView To Brown So I Use This Adapter For My ListView :

```
public class RankingListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<RankingItem> RankingItems;
int Po;

public RankingListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RankingItem> navDrawerItems, int p) {
    this.context = context;
    this.RankingItems = navDrawerItems;
    this.Po = p;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return RankingItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return RankingItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ranking_list_item, null);
    }

    TextView TVRank = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVRank);
    TextView TVUser = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVUser);
    TextView TVLVL = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVLVL);
    TextView TVScore = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVScore);
    Typeface TEng = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/English.ttf");
    Typeface TNum = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Nums.ttf");

    TVRank.setText(RankingItems.get(position).getRank());
    TVRank.setTypeface(TNum);
    TVUser.setText(RankingItems.get(position).getUsername());
    TVUser.setTypeface(TEng);
    TVLVL.setText(RankingItems.get(position).getLVL());
    TVLVL.setTypeface(TNum);
    TVScore.setText(RankingItems.get(position).getScore());
    TVScore.setTypeface(TNum);

    if (position == Po) {
        TVRank.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b38620"));
        TVUser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b38620"));
        TVLVL.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b38620"));
        TVScore.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b38620"));
    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

But When I Run My App I See This : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyH3K.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA2QX.png)

What Is The Problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write else condition also for color

```
 if (position == Po) {
    TVRank.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b38620"));
    TVUser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b38620"));
    TVLVL.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b38620"));
    TVScore.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b38620"));
}
else
{
    //set default color of your texts.
    TVRank.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    TVUser.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    TVLVL.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    TVScore.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);        
}
```

Comment: Yeeeeeees That Is Work Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put an `else` condition and write what color has to be set in your `else` condition. Try like this

```
if (position == Po) {
    TVRank.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b38620"));
    TVUser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b38620"));
    TVLVL.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b38620"));
    TVScore.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b38620"));
}else{
      //set your required color to the required textView here
}
```

Comment: Yeeeeeees That Is Work Thanks

Comment: @MobinVahdati please accept my answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: Both Of Them Is True But I Just Accept On Of Them :(